# Create a user who cannot see other bank objects

Tags: postgresql, sql-grant

How do I create a user who does not see any bank object. Only the materialized view that I will release to him via grant?

I create the user like this:

`CREATE USER PAPER WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'secure password' NOSUPERUSER NOINHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION VALID UNTIL 'infinite';`

`GRANT SELECT ON vw_visao TO user;`

but when I logged in with him on pgadmin3 they can see the entire structure of the bank.

Like seeing how many tables you have, the functions and the sql within the functions and the ddl of the tables. Do not select anything for lack of privilege.

I am trying to prevent the user from being allowed to execute these commands.

There are several interesting options, see some examples:

```
\d  list the database tables
\dv list database views
\di list enter code here the indexes of the database
\db list the tablespaces
\l list the databases
\dg list existing roles (users or groups)
\conninfo displays information about the current connection
\h list SQL commands
\h command displays details about the command
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that inside a single database in PostgreSQL.

One possibility would be to use a `postgres_fdw` foreign table to refer to a table in a different database, whose definition could not be seen.